# Modal popup error in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2013

```
 var options = 
    {
        url: "http://siteUrl/_layouts/Page.aspx?ID=6",
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
        title: 'Attach File',
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

I have tried this javascript code. But it gives me error.
Error in url of modal popup .It will redirect to this following url:
res://ieframe.dll/http_404.htm#SiteURL?IsDlg=1

Comment: What url do you use?

Comment: What is the value of the variable "url" ?

Comment: Thanx @Anatoly Mironov. Sorry Its my mistake. I have passed url "http://siteUrl/_layouts/Page.aspx?ID=6"

Comment: @Magnus Hansson I have changed url.. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you navigate to http://siteUrl/_layouts/Page.aspx?ID=6 directly in the browser? On the other hand, is there any other page you can try to open in the modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking closely on your code I see that you are having one extra "," after the title. That may case a problem for you. 
It should be defined like this:

```
var options = {
title: "My Dialog Title",
width: 400,
height: 600,
url: "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx" };
```

No "," after the last parameter.

Comment: Thnk you so much @Magnus Hasson. It's working for me...

Comment: Welcome .. sometimes it is the smallest things. I made that error once myself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Can i suggest the following? This is taken from a SP2010 solutions i developed but I'm sure it will work just the same...

```
<a id="idHomePageNewItem" onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event,&quot;http://siteUrl/_layouts/Page.aspx?ID=6&amp;RootFolder=&quot;);javascript:return false;" href="/_layouts/Page.aspx?ID=6&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self" style="width: 212px; height: 50px;">Your link text here</a>
```

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: Hello @Stephen but how can i write this following anchor tag in my custom page??

Comment: I made my page a webpart page and added it via the HTML source editor...

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same system's behavior when page didn't exist with such URL (i thought it was, but actually it wasn't - usually, the simplest mistakes is harder to find). I always start checking URL first now - hopefully, it helps someone.